# Rails 4 on Heroku with 'protected_attributes' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, omniauth, mass-assignment

I don't know where else to turn with this: I have spent many hours on my project, a recruiting events website for college students, but have reached quite the impasse.

In short, I plodded along in localhost - adding components like Devise; Omniauth authentication via providers Facebook, LinkedIn, and Google - building a website I was proud of along the way. Everything appeared to be working just fine, but once I pushed to 'heroku master' things started breaking big time.

I think the issues are most likely in or around:I have an **Authentication** model to keep track of a single user's authentication providers, alongside the **User** model (where all the oauth code is kept).

Without further ado, here is my app's heroku domain and my code:

http://lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com/ 
https://gist.github.com/mecampbellsoup/6357855

The things breaking which I suspect are related:

- 'heroku run rake db:seed' following 'pg:reset' & 'rake db:migrate'... instead of seeding with the contents of the seed file itself, a single blank Event and Company are created; more on this below
- the routing and action relating to the omniauth request seems to be working just fine, according to the heroku logs (below) but no user nor authentication is actually created:
- when, after resetting postgres db, I try to run 'heroku run rake db:create' or 'db:setup' I am whined at as follows:

> ☁  duke_recruits [master] heroku run rake db:setup 
>   Running `rake db:setup` attached to terminal... up, run.5886 
>   FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres" 
>   DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.

- also, 'heroku run rake db:seed' *appears* to be doing its thing, but then my db only has 1 empty Event and 1 empty Company:

> ☁  duke_recruits [master] heroku run rake db:seed 
>   Running `rake db:seed` attached to terminal... up, run.1767
>
> ☁  duke_recruits [master] heroku run rails c 
>   Running `rails c` attached to terminal... up, run.6135 
>   Event.allLoading production environment (Rails 4.0.0) 
>   irb(main):001:0> Event.all 
>   => #ActiveRecord::Relation [#Event id: 1, title: nil, location: nil, description: nil, date: nil, end_date: nil, company_id: nil, created_at: "2013-08-27 19:30:06", updated_at: "2013-08-27 19:30:06"] 
>   irb(main):002:0> Company.all 
>   => #ActiveRecord::Relation [#Company id: 1, name: nil, description: nil, website: nil, logo: nil, created_at: "2013-08-27 19:30:06", updated_at: "2013-08-27 19:30:06"]

Logs (upon opening the app on heroku and trying google authentication):

> 2013-08-27T19:49:18.701285+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:49:18 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:49:18.701019+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:49710
> 2013-08-27T19:49:18.701019+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
> 2013-08-27T19:49:18.701019+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
> 2013-08-27T19:49:18.701019+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
> 2013-08-27T19:49:18.701019+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:49:18 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:49:19.131115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com fwd="68.175.76.48" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=442ms status=304 bytes=0
> 2013-08-27T19:49:19.221284+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-b44a43097f814ac98347f6802323e25f.js host=lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com fwd="68.175.76.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=0
> 2013-08-27T19:49:49.440894+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:49:49 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:49:49.440894+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:49:49 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:49:49.515520+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com fwd="68.175.76.48" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=80ms status=304 bytes=0
> 2013-08-27T19:50:48.534099+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:50:48 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:50:48.534099+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:50:48 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:50:48.575279+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com fwd="68.175.76.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=51ms status=304 bytes=0
> 2013-08-27T19:50:52.293922+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:50:52 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:50:52.293922+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:50:52 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:50:52.591752+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_up host=lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com fwd="68.175.76.48" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=307ms status=304 bytes=0
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.368352+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:00 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.368352+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:00 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.368926+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-27T19:51:00.368823 #2]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.392262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/auth/google_oauth2 host=lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com fwd="68.175.76.48" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=33ms status=302 bytes=469
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.715597+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:00 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.715597+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:00 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.716822+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-27T19:51:00.716706 #2]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.997866+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=40ecfd10739cb874b5c461fc00cfd72ec4fcb694ef3a6878&code=4/D_(omitted_for_security)_GBlmiYhY(partially_omitted)E9yth.QpxI3jdcGpYYshQV0ieZDAoQOqyCgQI" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:00 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.997866+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=10739cb874b5c461fc00cfd72ec4fcb694ef3a6878&code=4/D_GBlmiYhY1rCvgdgE9yth.QpxI3jdcGpYYshQV0ieZDAoQOqyCgQI" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:00 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:00.998508+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-27T19:51:00.998379 #2]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
> 2013-08-27T19:51:02.188467+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:02 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:02.188467+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 68.175.76.48 at 2013-08-27 19:51:02 +0000
> 2013-08-27T19:51:02.234644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/sign_up host=lit-everglades-7633.herokuapp.com fwd="68.175.76.48" dyno=web.1 connect=9ms service=52ms status=304 bytes=0

Please let me know what questions you have for me and if I can clarify anything at all. I really appreciate your time & help SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a pg:reset, you can run the create command, but it usually gives you output like:

```
slkdjfs0dslkd already exists
```

So then you'll know that your database is created and ready to be used.  Before you can seed though make sure you migrate.  Just the standard heroku way

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Then seed as normal

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to point out that my particular problem was WAY TRICKIER: basically, I had the 'protected_attributes' gem that Rails 4 recommends (for handling lineage mass assignments in your controllers from prior Rails versions) and this apparently [screws up Heroku's precompilation process](https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes/issues/13). Imagine how long it took me to figure this one out!

Comment: Wow, I'm really glad you mentioned that.  I have a rails 3 app that is about to go through the update to rails 4, with the intention being to use protected_attributes,  and I would have been banging my head on this gotcha!